# libgdx Nearest texture filtering is forced?

Tags: java, libgdx, textures, filtering

hi i am making a simple import from blender and i have a problem in texture filtering. 
the texture appears to be filtered by nearest min filter 
[nearest min filter , linear mag filter issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqNw3.png)
but questioning its texture description attribute says its linear.
also setting it to linear filtering doesnot change the situation

[image]
http://s10.postimg.org/wgmxoz5fd/issue.png

Comment: I don't think you're seeing nearest filtering. You're seeing a lack of anisotropic filtering. I don't think LibGDX has convenient methods for turning that on. You'd have to call OpenGL directly.

Comment: thanks for your reply 
i tried using .gl commands to enable things like mipmapping and linear filters - i thought its disabled - but with no success ,, i will try again to find something related to anistropic filtering ... thanks (Y)

Comment: i tried everything i could with no success 
-first the anisotropic filtering 
*got the max anisotropy and setting it to opengl texture

-second enabling mipmaping while loading the texture 

this is frustrating me , should be a simple problem to solve
my last guess is that the sampler in the shader is forcing something 
will try that tomorrow...

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer:
As of libGDX 1.9.11, the Texture class has a `setAnisotropicFilter` method, used like this:

```
myTexture.setAnisotropicFilter(16f);
```

---

Original answer:
I don't think LibGDX has methods available for turning on anisotropic filtering, but you can try this helper class. Aniostropic filtering is not guaranteed to be supported by OpenGL ES, so it has to check for availability. I haven't tested this with LibGDX in the past year, so I'm not positive it still works correctly.

```
public class Anisotropy {

    private static boolean anisotropySupported = false;
    private static boolean checkComplete = false;
    private static float maxAnisotropySupported = 1.0f;

    /**Applies the given anisotropic level to the texture. Returns the anisotropy value that was applied, 
     * based on device's maximum capability.
     * @param texture The texture to apply anisotropy to.
     * @param anisotropy The anisotropic level to apply. (Will be reduced if device capability is less.)
     * @return The anisotropic level that was applied, or -1.0 if anisotropy is not supported by the device.
     */
    public static float setTextureAnisotropy(Texture texture, float anisotropy){
        if (isSupported()) {
            texture.bind();
            float valueApplied = Math.min(maxAnisotropySupported, anisotropy);
            Gdx.gl20.glTexParameterf(GL20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL20.GL_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT, valueApplied);
            return valueApplied;
        } else {
            return -1f;
        }
    }
    
    public static boolean isSupported(){
        if (!checkComplete){
            GL20 gl = Gdx.gl;
            if (gl != null){
                if (Gdx.graphics.supportsExtension("GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic")){
                    anisotropySupported = true;
                    FloatBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.newFloatBuffer(16);
                    Gdx.gl20.glGetFloatv(GL20.GL_MAX_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT, buffer);
                    maxAnisotropySupported = buffer.get(0);
                }
                checkComplete = true;
            } else 
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("cannot check GL state before libgdx initialized");
        }
        return anisotropySupported;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: tried it , no thing changed 
and in the original that was my code 

  FloatBuffer buf = BufferUtils.newFloatBuffer(64);
        Gdx.gl.glGetFloatv(GL20.GL_MAX_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT,buf);
        float maxAniso = buf.get(0);

        System.out.println(maxAniso);
        groundTexture.bind();
        Gdx.gl.glTexParameterf(GL20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL20.GL_TEXTUR_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT, Math.min(16, maxAniso));

thanks for help anyway

Comment: did you generate the mipmaps?

Comment: yep i tried the given code 

TextureAttribute myTex =(TextureAttribute)GroundInstance.materials.get(0).get(TextureAttribute.Diffuse);
Texture groundTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("badlogic.jpg"), Pixmap.Format.RGB565,true);
groundTexture.setWrap(myTex.textureDescription.uWrap,myTex.textureDescription.vWrap);
groundTexture.setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.MipMapLinearLinear, Texture.TextureFilter.MipMapLinearLinear);  myTex.textureDescription.texture.load(groundTexture.getTextureData());

Comment: i am overriding the texture in the imported model ~g3db 
and the texture is changed to the new one "badlogic.jpg"
but the problem is the same 
questioning the generation of mipmaps after overriding 
by <textureDescription.texture.getTextureData().useMipMaps()>
returned true , rather than false in the original g3db texture